# Login and registration by FB. What should be passed in the logon package so that it can be verified?

Tags: facebook, authentication, registration

I have a question about login and registration by fb.

How Fb API authorizes whit the application server?
Is it a token, id etc?
If yes , is  it  always constant and does not change?
Does API Fb hold information to what application the user is  or has logged in?

Comment: did you heard about the RTFM process?

Comment: Yes, it uses tokens, because it is basically an OAuth2 implementation. No, the standard user tokens are short-lived. They can be extended to e valid for up to 60 days. Details, see Facebook docs.